# Adjust image size to card flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I'm trying to adjust all pictures (in trailing ListTile) to be as the THIRD one (to lower card).

[image]

This is my code so far :

```dart
return Card(
child:ListTile(...
...
   trailing: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
              return FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                height: constraints.maxHeight,
                placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                image: picture,
              );
            },
          ),
```

I appreciate any help

Comment: Try to use the `fit` property in the FadeInImage. [BoxFit enum](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html)

Comment: YOU'RE AWESOME! Thanks a lot @Manuel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By @Manuel suggestion - this is how it worked:

```
            ...trailing: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
            return FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              height: constraints.maxHeight,
              width: constraints.maxWidth/3,
              placeholder: kTransparentImage,
              image: picture,
            );
          },
        ),
```